# Are there other characters with combined techniques in Dragon Ball other than Gohan and Piccolo's Demon Flash of Death?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

Spoilers from manga 56

> For trying to defeat 73, Gohan and Piccolo use a combined technique called Demon's Flash of Death, (Masenkōkōsappō) a combination of Demon's Flash of Light (Masenko) and Special Beam Cannon ("Demon's Penetrating, Killing Light Gun", Makankōsappō)

Are there other characters with combined techniques like them in the series?

Comment: Unless you are specifically referencing a particular series, the Dragonball series should be sufficient for asking general questions across the franchise l.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some on the wiki under [Team Attacks](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Team_attacks) or [Combined Techniques](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Combined_techniques).
As an example the [Final Kamehameha](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Final_Kamehameha) of Goku and Vegeta:

> Final Kamehameha (ファイナルかめはめ波 Fainaru Kamehameha, lit. "Final Kamehame Wave") is a combination of Goku's Kamehameha and Vegeta's Final Flash used by Vegito. The move can also be created when Goku and Vegeta combine the Super Kamehameha and the Final Flash simultaneously.